# Download file from s3 with the latest version 1.11.218 of java-s3-sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file uploaded to s3 storage and referenced by following link

> https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-config/my-backend/key.pem

And I want to be able to download this file using java s3-sdk.

Documentation Link :

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html

states that to download a file, I can use the following code:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());        
S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(
                  new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();
// Process the objectData stream.
objectData.close()
```

And one can find multiple examples of downloading file on the site. However, there are no hints on what is `bucketName` and what is `key`, provided you are given a link like my link above.

So far I've tried to use

```
bucketName = s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-config/my-backend/
key = key.pem

bucketName = s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-config/
key = my-backend/key.pem
```

But these combinations result in 403 error for me.

Could you please give a hint on what should I use for `bucketName` and `key` provided I have the link (link below)  for the file?

> https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-config/my-backend/key.pem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given your example URL:

Bucket name: `my-config`

Key: `my-backend/key.pem`

And you'll also need to specify the bucket region, which is `eu-west-1`, unless you have it configured as your default region already.